# Access my Pi from another network for file transfers

Tags: networking, server, internet, file-server

*Apologies in advance if this has been answered on here before but could not find an answer specific to my needs*

**The Question:** what is the simplest way to setup the Pi so that I can access it from another network and upload/download files with something like filezilla ?

**Situation (if interested, or informs a better solution):** 
I have my Pi (Raspbian OS) set up for (legal, of course) torrent downloads with Deluge and downloads I don't want to keep my main PC on for, for power consumption reasons (I have a terrible connection speed so the average download takes very long).

All files relating to this are saved on a USB drive which I access via filezilla from my main computer across my local network.

I will be moving away for uni and want to use it for its current purpose as well as file management (upload/downloading files, uploading .torrent files to the deluge dump folder).

If possibly will hopefully mount another USB drive (via USB extension cable) for my parents to plug their USB drives in if they need files from me or want me to see files from them (ultimately limiting amount or technological engagement for my parents, otherwise I would simply use dropbox or something for simple file drops)

Answer (score 1):

[OwnCloud and BitTorrent Sync](http://blog.bittorrent.com/2013/05/23/how-i-created-my-own-personal-cloud-using-bittorrent-sync-owncloud-and-raspberry-pi/) might be your solution.

I myself use the Owncloud as an private DropBox. You can share access to folders to some people and access it from everywhere (if the router ports are configured correctly).

However, the speed is related to your internet provider.

To mount another bigger USB Drive you can configure the ownCloud easily with (im my case):

```
sudo nano /var/www/owncloud/config/config.php
```

and edit the line:

```
'datadirectory' => '/media/<YOUR_USB_DRIVE>/<SUB_DIR>',
```

Hope you will be happy with that. 
In case of further questions: Just ask. :)

Answer (score 0):

First of, I use transmission for torrenting, since it has a web UI. I forward the port to my router (check with your ISP if that port is open),I mention this just because it's easy of use.

So regarding your real question, you could just do the same you are doing right now, just open the ports to the outside world. You might want to/need to change the default port to something higher/something your ISP doesn't block.

In combination with no-ip.org you can access it more easily.